# How to change smoothly my div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a pagination that i want to change the content of container by click on it.
it works, but i want that it happen smoothly.

```
<div id='container>
    <div id='0' class='box'></div>
    <div id='1' class='box'></div>
    <div id='2' class='box'></div>
</div>
```

style :

```
 #container{'
    position:relative
 }

.box{
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
 }

.box:first-child{
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

by click on my pagination buttons :

```
$(function () {
    var obj = $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: 3,
        visiblePages: 2,
        prev:'Prev',
        next:'Next',
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            console.info(page);
            page=page-1;
            $(".box").hide(function () {
                $("#"+page).show();
            });
        }
    });
```

how can i do this smoothly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Define "smoothly". Also, do some research into [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), where it mentions using the `duration` argument to make the animation occur over a period of time, and [Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) where it details all of the animation possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options

**In Jquery Way:-**

Use `fadeIn` `fadeOut` in place of `show` `hide`

```
$(".box").fadeOut("slow",function () {
  $("#"+page).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**In CSS Way:-**

Use `transition` to animate. but in this case you only can play smoothly with `opacity` and `visibility` and not `display`

```
  .box{
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0;
     visibility:hidden;
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     -moz-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     -o-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     -ms-transition: all 2s ease 0s;*/
     transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     }
```

Comment: fade in and fade out doesn't change visibility property!!

Comment: no it wont change visibility property . it will change `opacity` while transforming and `display` at the end

Comment: The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. thats why i recommend to use it

Comment: but your css code contains visibility hidden too, that causes problem. when fadeIn happens => opacity=1 but the div is still hidden .

Comment: @Hamid Both of them are different methods to do this. i have mentioned it. You can do it in eighther one way(CSS or jquery). i recommend you take only to take the jQuery method.

Comment: something  is interesting for me is that fadeIn() method animate the opacity of matched element, but when the opacity=0 it can not change it to 1 and unhide it!!

Comment: No not like that. fadeIn changes opacity from 0 to 1 and then makes display block . fadeOut changes opacity from 1 to 0 and then makes display none .

Comment: ok.you means that it doesn't set the opacity property at all. and we should use fadeTo() method or css() to set opacity property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transitions with opacity rather than hiding an showing the elements.

```
.box {
   position: absolute;
   display: block; // not required but do not keep it as display: none
   opacity: 0; // make the div invisible!
   transition: opacity 1s linear; // tell the browser how and what to transition
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear; // webkit support
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear; // firefox support
}

.box.active {
   opacity: 1; // only applies when a box has the class .box and .active
}
```

Instead of calling .show() to show the element you can add and remove the active class on each div.